What are Pratisakhyas?
I came across a book named Katyayana's Pratisakhya of White Yajurveda. It is in Sanskrit. What is Pratisakhya? What is the connection of Pratisakhya with the Vedas?

Pratisakhyas are treatises dealing with correct pronunciation of the Vaidika mantras.

@অনু Is it part of Vedangas (like Niruktas)?

Pratishakhyas (प्रातिशाख्य) exists for every Veda. It is a technical supplement aimed at shakhins to preserve correct vocal rendering and therefore transmission of a given Veda, transmission is called shakha, hence the name "Pratishakhya". Pratishakhyas contain phonetics-shiksha, some grammar-vyakarana, chandas-prosody. Basically they are guides for pronunciation, these do not mess with meaning, etymology or details of vyakarana.
They are not a part of Vedanga. They are technical base for shakha.
